# replace based on Vlookup to a list

Tags: excel, vba, replace, vlookup

I have an 80 byte text file that I am extracting data from. I am needing to convert the result of the cells(j,5) = Mid(tempstr, 43,13) into a dollar figure.

Mid results:
000000148012H

The right most character is an "H" and needs to convert to "8" based on the table below

Right Character

```
B   2   1
C   3   1
D   4   1
E   5   1
F   6   1
G   7   1
H   8   1
I   9   1
{   0   1
J   1   -1
K   2   -1
L   3   -1
M   4   -1
N   5   -1
O   6   -1
P   7   -1
Q   8   -1
R   9   -1
}   0   -1
```

The excel formula works in the sheet as a seperate cell after the macros is called, but I need this to work in the VBA code for this sheet in cells (j,5), and Cells(j,6). E2= the mid result (000000148012H), data sheet = the table above

Excel Formula:

```
=REPLACE(E2,13,1,VLOOKUP(RIGHT(E2,1),'Data 
Sheet'!$A$2:$C$21,2,FALSE))*VLOOKUP(RIGHT(E2,1),'Data 
Sheet'!$A$2:$C$21,3,FALSE)*0.01
```

Reslut= 14801.28

Current VBA Code:

```
If Val(Mid(tempstr, 13, 12)) <> 0 And Val(Mid(tempstr, 25, 7)) = "0000077" Then
    Worksheets(2).Activate
    If j = 1 Then
        Cells(j, 1) = "SSN"
        Cells(j, 2) = "Transaction"
        Cells(j, 3) = "Source"
        Cells(j, 4) = "Fund Symbol"
        Cells(j, 5) = "Cash/Market Value"
        Cells(j, 6) = "Shares"
        Cells(j, 7) = "Cost Converted"
        Cells(j, 8) = "C/M/V Converted"
        Cells(j, 9) = "Shares Converted"
        j = j + 1
    End If
        Cells(j, 1) = Mid(tempstr, 13, 12)  'SSN
        Cells(j, 2) = Mid(tempstr, 32, 3)   'Transaction
        Cells(j, 3) = Mid(tempstr, 35, 2)   'Source
        Cells(j, 4) = Mid(tempstr, 39, 4)   'Fund Symbol
        Cells(j, 5) = Mid(tempstr, 43, 13)  'Cash/Market Value
        Cells(j, 6) = Mid(tempstr, 56, 12)  'Shares
        Cells(j, 7) = Mid(tempstr, 68, 13)  'Cost
        j = j + 1
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not received any answer to my question so I simply hard coded the values as shown below. seems to work great, but if anything ever changes in the file it will be a lot to update.

```
   If Val(Mid(tempstr, 13, 12)) <> 0 And Val(Mid(tempstr, 25, 7)) = "0000077" Then
    Worksheets(2).Activate
    If j = 1 Then
        Cells(j, 1) = "SSN"
        Cells(j, 2) = "Transaction"
        Cells(j, 3) = "Source"
        Cells(j, 4) = "Fund Symbol"
        Cells(j, 5) = "Cash/Market Value"
        Cells(j, 6) = "Shares"
        Cells(j, 7) = "Cost"
        j = j + 1
        End If
        Cells(j, 1) = Mid(tempstr, 13, 12)                                                 'SSN
        Cells(j, 2) = Mid(tempstr, 32, 3)                                                  'Transaction
        Cells(j, 3) = Mid(tempstr, 35, 2)                                                  'Source
        Cells(j, 4) = Mid(tempstr, 39, 4)                                                   'Fund Symbol
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "A" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "1") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "B" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "2") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "C" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "3") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "D" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "4") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "E" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "5") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "F" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "6") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "G" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "7") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "H" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "8") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "I" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "9") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "{" Then Cells(j, 5) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "0") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "J" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "1") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "K" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "2") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "L" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "3") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "M" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "4") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "N" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "5") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "O" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "6") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "P" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "7") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "Q" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "8") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "R" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "9") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 55, 1) = "}" Then Cells(j, 5) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 43, 12) & "0") * 0.01           'Cash/Market Value
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "A" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "1") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "B" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "2") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "C" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "3") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "D" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "4") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "E" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "5") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "F" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "6") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "G" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "7") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "H" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "8") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "I" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "9") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "{" Then Cells(j, 6) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "0") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "J" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "1") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "K" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "2") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "L" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "3") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "M" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "4") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "N" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "5") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "O" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "6") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "P" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "7") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "Q" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "8") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "R" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "9") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 67, 1) = "}" Then Cells(j, 6) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 56, 11) & "0") * 0.01          'Shares
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "A" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "1") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "B" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "2") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "C" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "3") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "D" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "4") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "E" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "5") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "F" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "6") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "G" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "7") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "H" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "8") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "I" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "9") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "{" Then Cells(j, 7) = 1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "0") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "J" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "1") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "K" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "2") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "L" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "3") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "M" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "4") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "N" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "5") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "O" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "6") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "P" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "7") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "Q" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "8") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "R" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "9") * 0.01
        If Mid(tempstr, 80, 1) = "}" Then Cells(j, 7) = -1 * (Mid(tempstr, 68, 12) & "0") * 0.01               'Cost
        j = j + 1
        End If
```